# The strong twin conjecture can be transformed into the unsolvability of a particular Diophantine equation

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let us consider the strong twin conjecture:

For all positive integer $n$ there exist a prime $p$ such that
$$n+4<p<2^n2^4$$ and $p$ is a prime and $p+2$ is a prime

Since the inequalities and the set of primes are both Diophantine, we can construct a polynomial $P(X)$ such that the strong twin conjecture is equivalent to the following statement:

For all positive integer $n$ there exist a prime $p$ such that $P(X)=0$ where $X$ is a vector of several variables.

Now, in a book by Matiyasevich's: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/hilberts-10th-problem

The author claim that the strong twin conjecture can be transformed into the unsolvability of a particular Diophantine equation.

Then my question is: How one can find this Diophantine equation or I am asking about a reference containing this equation.

Comment: I think the book itself explains how to transform any algorithm with bounded running time into a Diophantine equation which is solvable if and only if that algorithm accepts for some integer $n$. Then take the algorithm which searches the numbers between $n+4$ and $2^n 2^4$ for a twin prime, and accepts if none is found.

Comment: I strongly doubt anyone has bothered to write down the equation you are after, but the procedure for generating the equation from the algorithm is, in principle, completely effective.

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward. There's an explicit Diophantine equation with 26 variables for when a number is prime and getting one for powers of 2 comes pretty easily from the material in the book, and should have 4 variables. You can combine Diophantine equations using the squaring trick. This should give you a Diophantine equation with 26 + 26 + 2+4 = 58 variables.

Comment: @Wojowu: Can you explain to me in few words how one can find that equation.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: But the problem is to find an equation that is unsolvable.

Comment: No, I can't. A complete explanation is the length of a book, and indeed the book you mention contains such an explanation.

Comment: @Safwane Right. The way Hilbert's 10th problem is solved by finding a systematic way of making a Diophantine equation which corresponds to any description of a  recursively enumerable set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computably_enumerable . Since whether certain recursively enumerable sets are in fact empty or not is undecidable, you get unsolvable Diophantine equations out as a bonus. But along the way, you get Diophantine equations which correspond to a whole bunch of sets, including the primes, and nice exponentials. Hence you can apply those parts of the construction.